# OpenLayers zoom scroll events are ignored if no layers are visible

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I've noticed that if all OpenLayers.Layers have visibility set to false, I can no longer zoom in and out using my mousewheel. I can still use the OpenLayers.Control.Zoom buttons, but no longer the mouse wheel.

Is there anyway to disable this 'feature'?

Edit:

Here is a jsfiddle link. Set the layer to invisible, then scroll, then set it back to visible. It doesn't change. Now set it invisible, use the zoom control button, then set it back visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/a8kK4/56/

Here's some code for how the map is instantiated because SO won't let me post jsfiddle without it:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
        div: "map",
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
        displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        layers: [ new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM() ]
    });
```

Comment: haven't seen this problem before.  can you post a link to a working exmaple (maybe jsfiddle, codepen, or your website)?

Comment: I second that. Interesting problem, but need to see code.

Comment: jsfiddle has been added

Comment: OK, I see the problem.

Comment: @Pondwater. Have you solved this yet? If not, I'll have a go.

Comment: @JohnBarça No not yet, the problem still persists.

Comment: @Pondwater. OK, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is to do with the onWheelEvent of the MouseWheel handler, see the code [here on github](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Handler/MouseWheel.js). The issue arises with the lines

```
if (!overScrollableDiv && overMapDiv) {
    if (allowScroll) {
```

as with the map hidden, you will never get it so that all of these conditions are met and therefore the call to this.wheelZoom(e) which actually does the zoom in/out never gets called. The behavior you are seeing is, therefore, by design.

One, somewhat crude way to fix this, is to override the whole function and just set the line where allowScroll is initialized to true, ie, you put the the whole function into your code, after the main OpenLayers.js has downloaded, and just change that one line

```
  OpenLayers.Handler.MouseWheel.prototype.onWheelEvent= function(e){        

    if (!this.map || !this.checkModifiers(e)) {
        return;
    }

    var overScrollableDiv = false;
    //CHANGE THIS LINE TO TRUE
    var allowScroll = true;
    var overMapDiv = false;

   //rest of function .......
   };
```

The problem of doing this is that a scroll will now happen if you use the mouse wheel anywhere. There is probably a more elegant way by changing the conditions under which the values of overMapDiv and allowScroll and overScrollableDiv get set. I could not get this to work on jsFiddle (I think due to version conflicts), but locally it worked as expected. I hope this helps.